# Flutter: How to create a responsive Stack() with two textfield and a button which crosses both textfields borders, in the middle

Tags: flutter, stack, border, responsive, positioning

i am trying to create an app for a dictionary. something like  "https://translate.google.com/". but i want the swap button to be in between of both field so it crosses both textfields borders. i have tried the code below but in some devices (height:480 vs height:2280 ) the Stack() children jumps over each other. How can i make it responsive?

```
 Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //first language
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: Material(
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                             labelText: 'first language',
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                 Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                              prefixText: ' ',
                              suffixStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
//second language
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Material(
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              labelText: 'second language',
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                              prefixText: ' ',
                              suffixStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
//REVERSE BUTTON in center
                    Align(

                      alignment: Alignment.center,

                      child: Flex(
                          //horizontaly
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          direction: Axis.horizontal,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Flexible(flex: 10, child: Container()),
                            Flexible(
                              flex: 5,
                              child: Flex(
                                //vertically
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                direction: Axis.vertical,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Flexible(
                                      flex: 25,
                                      fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                      child: Container(

                                          )),
                                  Flexible(
                                    flex: 25,
                                    fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                    child: MaterialButton(
                                      child: ClipOval(
                                        child: Container(
                                         color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 90, 128, 1),
                                         child: Center(
                                            child: Icon(Icons.swap_vert,
                                                size: 33, color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Flexible(
                                      flex: 25,
                                      fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                      child: Container()),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Flexible(flex: 10, child: Container()),
                          ]),
                    ),



                  ],
                )),
```

Comment: you need `Positioned` widget

Comment: thank you for quick reply. do you think using Positioned will handle device sizes 480x854 (219 dpi) and 1080x2280 (403 dpi)?

Comment: i have  tried Positioned widget instead of Align() and styled it in 1080x2280 (403 dpi) size . Then i checked it in 1080x1920 (443 dpi) screen size and again the swap button jumps again. at this time little bit top.

Comment: post an exact image with what you expect to get

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oau6Ywe9vHbDEx4aMeyD-mycM_aE6Bt-/view

Comment: see `LayoutBuilder(
builder: (ctx, constraints) {
print(constraints.smallest);
var half = constraints.smallest.height / 2;
return Stack(
children: <Widget>[
Positioned.fill(bottom: half, child: TextField(minLines: null, maxLines: null, expands: true,)),
Positioned.fill(top: half, child: TextField(minLines: null, maxLines: null, expands: true,)),
Positioned.fill(top: half - 40, bottom: half - 40, child: FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.contain, child: Icon(Icons.school))),
],
);
},
),`

Comment: yes it works perfectly for different sized devices. thank a lot. it has been almost one week, for me working on it.

Comment: sure, your welcome